# Fetching something from a table using information from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is for a real estate website - they display thousands of ads stored inside a database - sadly the photos and the ads are stored in two different tables in the database. The information about the properties are under a table called properties - the images are stored in a table called `propertyImages` - the one thing they have in common is their `propspaceId` - this is how they are linked.

Some properties have more than one image - lets say an ad with four photos will have ONE unique `propspaceID` for that ad (inside the properties table) - but the photos that belong to that ad inside the propertyImages table has that ID for all the photos that go with that ad.

Basically, ALL ads have a ranking number. This ranking number is made up of different factors and I've been able to make this work. However, one of the factors is the number of images each advert has - the old programmer wrote this code:

```
$property['totalImages'] = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `propertyImages` WHERE propspaceId=".$property['propspaceId']));
```

I can't seem to understand this, or write a new one. This code doesn't work. Then, later in the code when I write the conditions, I wrote something like this.

```
switch($property['totalImages']){
      case $property['totalImages'] >= 1 :
          $rank+=100;
          break;
  }
```

..etc.

The second code isn't the problem. I need to find a way to fetch the number of photos inside the `propertyImages` table with matching `propspaceId`(`s`) and then for example if there are 4 recurring values for the `propspaceId = 45666`, I want the variable to be 4.

Answer (score 1):

The second code is the problem.  You either need to convert it to an `if` or do it like this:

```
switch(true) {

      case ($property['totalImages'] >= 1):
          $rank += 100;
          break;
}
```

In your `switch` you are comparing the integer value of `$property['totalImages']` to the boolean result of `$property['totalImages'] >= 1`.

To use an `if` something like:

```
if($property['totalImages'] >= 1) {
          $rank += 100;
}
elseif($property['totalImages'] == 0) {
          //rank = something else
}
//other stuff, you didn't show more than 1 condition
```

Comment: If i decide to use an IF function, do I just do it like this:
    if($property['totalImages']>=1){rank+=10;} and then just keep writing IF functions? or do I use else if?

Comment: With an `if` you use the expressions like you have. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) as number_photos from propertyImages where propspaceId = ?
```

Comment: Shouldn't I put propspaceId instead of * inside count?

Comment: Not necessarily. Count(*) will count the rows. Since propertyImages contains one row per image, if your property has 4 images then the table propertyImages will have 4 rows with propspaceId = ?.

Comment: But upon closer inspection, the problem is coming from the switch, like AbraCadaver said. So try looking into that.